# SQL Server : generating varchar as number

Tags: sql, cursor, sql-update, ascii, declare

I have done scripts which I need for generating `varchar` as number but its only work for MySQL but I have SQL Server where it does not work.

**Scripts is here:**

```
SET @reference = 0;

UPDATE dbo.expozitura 
SET reference_subjektu = LPAD(@reference := @reference + 1, 8, '0') 
ORDER BY cislo_subjektu ASC;
```

This scripts in SQL Server still has a problem with syntax: it doesn't like ":".

I explain my problem so I have some `varchar` data in `reference_subjekt`. This data is not important for me so but I need generating new data to this column as number but it is still `varchar` type.

**For example**

My actually data is:

```
reference_subjektu
TR.Mac
Orgins
Kernel
Tybru
Serenity
```

But I need replace my before data for this data:

```
reference_subjektu
"00000001"
"00000002"
"00000003"
"00000004"
"00000005" and etc.....
```

Have you any idea please?

My SQL Server information:

- Version: 11.0.2218

I try use your scripts: (a1ex07)

I using this from your code:

```
UPDATE dbo.expozitura 
SET reference_subjektu = replicate('0', 8 - len(rn) ) + b.rn
FROM dbo.expozitura  a 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT dbo.expozitura.cislo_subjektu, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cislo_subjektu) rn
   FROM dbo.expozitura
) b ON (b.cislo_subjektu = a.cislo_subjektu)
```

My primary key is `cislo_subjektu`

And its really return me only 123456 and etc to rows. But I need different style.

MY DB output when I used scripts:

```
cislo_subjektu  reference_subjektu  organizace  adresa_ulice    psc ico
1                       1                2                          729544866
2                       2                0        Linkoln 507       729544866
3                       3                0                     403 31   729544866
4                       4                0                          729544866
5                       5                0        Linkoln 66   578 99   729544866
6                       6                0                     558 41   729544866
```

Do you know that where I have problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have a primary key `dbo.expozitura.expozitura_id` column, the following should do the job:

```
UPDATE dbo.expozitura 
SET reference_subjektu = replicate('0', 8-len(rn) )+b.rn
FROM dbo.expozitura  a 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT expozitura_id, 
   CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cislo_subjektu) AS varchar) AS rn
   FROM dbo.expozitura
) b ON (b.expozitura_id = a.expozitura_id)
```

Comment: I just wonder why minus... Query is working and doing what's asked.

Comment: your scripts is work, it updated on 123456

    But i need this type:
    reference_subjektu
    "00000001"
    "00000002"
    "00000003"
    "00000004"
    "00000005" and etc.....

But your update return me this:
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6

Comment: @Radek Tarant: Are you sure? I may have initially put version without `CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cislo_subjektu) AS varchar) AS rn` ( it was just `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cislo_subjektu)  AS rn`, but fixed it myself withing couple seconds...

Comment: i edited my first post, check it please if i have correct with your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This line isn't valid:

```
ORDER BY cislo_subjektu ASC
```

Order by isn't a valid clause in UPDATE statement.

This line isn't valid as well:

```
LPAD(@reference:=@reference+1, 8, '0')
```

You can't increment @reference this way.

This is th proper way to do this:

```
WITH UpdateData  As
(
SELECT reference_subjektu ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cislo_subjektu ASC) AS RN
FROM dbo.expozitura
)

UPDATE dbo.expozitura
SET reference_subjektu = replicate('0', 8-len(RN) )
FROM dbo.expozitura 
INNER JOIN UpdateData ON expozitura.reference_subjektu = UpdateData.reference_subjektu
```

Comment: it still say me that incorrect syntax with this char in my scripts ":"

Comment: and if i remove char ":" and order by soo that i earn this warnings:

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'LPAD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: it still write me this problem:

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
'LPAD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Yosi : Didn't you see it's about SQLServer which doesn't have `LPAD`?